# NetworkX: why are some connected components seen as disconnected when they are not?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges, connected-components

I am reading a `shapefile` and creating a NetworkX graph out of it like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.read_shp('C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder\case_study.shp') 
posy = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(G.nodes())}
Y=nx.Graph() #Empty graph
Y.add_nodes_from(posy.keys()) #Add nodes preserving coordinates
l=[set(x) for x in G.edges()]
edg=[tuple(k for k,v in posy.items() if v in sl) for sl in l] #Map the G.edges start and endpoints onto pos
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Y,posy,node_size=10,node_color='blue')
Y.add_edges_from(edg)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Y,posy)
plt.xlim(460000, 541000)
plt.ylim(380000, 480000)
plt.xlabel('Easting [m]')
plt.ylabel('Northing [m]')
```

This graph should have 2 connected components. Instead, if I check, I get 9 connected components:

```
In[1]: gY = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(Y))
In[2]: len(gY)
Out[2]: 9
```

This means that a few topological errors were inherited from the shapefile itself. I can brutally identify these components:

```
nx.draw(gY[0],posy,node_size=100,node_color='r',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[1],posy,node_size=100,node_color='blue',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[2],posy,node_size=100,node_color='green',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[3],posy,node_size=100,node_color='grey',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[4],posy,node_size=100,node_color='brown',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[5],posy,node_size=100,node_color='yellow',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[6],posy,node_size=100,node_color='orange',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[7],posy,node_size=100,node_color='purple',with_labels=False,font_size=8)
nx.draw(gY[8],posy,node_size=100,node_color='white',with_labels=False,font_size=8)

plt.xlim(460000, 541000)
plt.ylim(380000, 480000)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

The graph should have two components only: the one dashed in black, and the one dashed in grey.

**My question:** if I zoom in around the red-purple-yellow area, I discover that the nodes are indeed connected, so there shouldn't be 3 connected components, but just one. Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Something clearly isn't working right.  Could you make case_study.shp available so we could investigate?

Comment: I think it'd be most beneficial if I could email you a few images, together with `case_study.shp`, so to show you what's going on. To what I've pointed out in the question, add the fact that whenever you add a new segment to `case_study.shp` that bridges the gap between two other segments that were erroneously not connected, `nx.read_shp` sees this new segment as a new component, although it is attached to an existing one. It also renders this new segment as shortened, as if it was not drawn to bridge the full gap between two points, but just part of it, ending up with one unattached edge.

Comment: @Aric were you able to figure this out?